# Apex Testing HttpCalloutMock failing

Tags: apex, httpcalloutmock

The method is for testing a class that use a soap envelope to check if an address exists and if it does return true, otherwise it returns false.  It implements Jennifer Symonds xpath to verify the field is there and if so returns true.   I wrote this mock, but it keeps coming back false, even though the id I am sending is valid.   What am I doing wrong here.

```
@isTest 
    private static void testMethod2() {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator2());
        Test.startTest();
        String output = UDPNewInstallOrder.checkAddress('1366604');
        //System.debug(output);
        System.assertEquals('true', output);
        Test.stopTest();


    }
```

The xpath part of the checkAddress method

```
String headend_code = xp.getText ('/Envelope/Body/FindServiceAddressByExampleResponse/FindServiceAddressByExampleResult/ServiceAddressList/ServiceAddressView/HeadendCode');
            if(headend_code == null) {
                return 'false';
            }else{
                return 'true';
            }
```

The class itself works fine, but I can't get this testing to go right.

The full class

```
  public static String checkAddress(String ServiceAddress){
            try{
            HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
            req2.setEndpoint('endpoint');
            req2.setMethod('POST');
            req2.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
            req2.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate');
            req2.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'Comet.Services.Interface/ICometInterfaceSvc/FindServiceAddressByExample');
            String request2 = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\r\n';
            request2 += '\t xmlns:ns0=\"Comet.Services.Interface\"\r\n';
            request2 += '\t xmlns:co1=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Comet.Model.Services\"\r\n';
            request2 += '\t xmlns:co2=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Comet.Model.Services.Request\"\r\n';
            request2+= '\t xmlns:co3=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Comet.Model.View\">\r\n';
            request2 += '\t <SOAP-ENV:Header/>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t <SOAP-ENV:Body>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t    <ns0:FindServiceAddressByExample>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t          <ns0:request>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t              <co1:ClientDateTime>2019-02-01T19:14:55</co1:ClientDateTime>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t              <co1:ClientId>000000</co1:ClientId>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t              <co1:UserId>000000</co1:UserId>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t              <co1:UserPassword>00000000</co1:UserPassword>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t              <co2:ServiceAddressExample>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t              <co3:ServiceAddressId>'+ServiceAddress+'</co3:ServiceAddressId>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t              </co2:ServiceAddressExample>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t          </ns0:request>';
            request2 += '\t     </ns0:FindServiceAddressByExample>';
            request2 += '\t </SOAP-ENV:Body>\r\n';
            request2 += '\t </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\r\n';                        
            req2.setBody(request2);



            Http http2 = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res2 = http2.send(req2);

            //String results2 = res2.getBody();
            String results = res2.getBody();

            String xml = results;

            //--> GET DATA FROM SOAP RESPONSE ENVELOPE AND STORE AS VARIABLES
            XPath xp = new XPath(xml);



            String headend_code = xp.getText ('/Envelope/Body/FindServiceAddressByExampleResponse/FindServiceAddressByExampleResult/ServiceAddressList/ServiceAddressView/HeadendCode');
            if(headend_code == null) {
                return 'false';
            }else{
                return 'true';
            }


            }catch(DmlException e) {
                return 'false';
            }

    }
```

MockHttpResponseGenerator2

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator2 implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        //Test mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        System.assertEquals('https://web121.udp.com:8001/CometAPI2018.9/CometInterfaceSvc.svc', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        res.setBody('<Envelope><Body><FindServiceAddressByExampleResponse><FindServiceAddressByExampleResult><ServiceAddressList><ServiceAddressView><HeadendCode>TEST</HeadendCode></ServiceAddressView></ServiceAddressList></FindServiceAddressByExampleResult></FindServiceAddressByExampleResponse></Body></Envelope>');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is enough code to tell what the issue might be. What does your Mock do? Where is the callout being made?

Comment: If you are testing a SOAP web service, then you need to use WebServiceMock instead of HttpCalloutMock

Comment: I am testing a soap web service.   So I will give that a try

Comment: No, I misunderstood. I am using a full on soap envelope request which should work with httpcalloutmock, as when I follow debug it actually queries the endpoint.   But it is still returning false.

Comment: Can you post the code for the MockHttpResponseGenerator class as well?

Comment: Just added the mock response.

Comment: I fixed a problem with the mock, and now it tests fine on that part.  However this bit of code is not actually being tested, if(checkAddress(udp_service_address_id) == 'false') {
            return 'The service address id in the address object is not valid';
        }

System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: True,  Actual: The service address id in the address object is not valid

Comment: You've lost me now. Is this a different problem now?

Comment: no part of the same problem, I was testing for this method checkAddress, so I created a mock class.  The mock classes passes, but this checkAddress(udp_service_address_id) == 'false' fails.   It should return true.    I thought that was suppose to be solved by creating the mock class, but I can't figure out how to test this properly then.   Should I just create a whole new post, and lay this out better?

Comment: Solved the problem by completely rewriting and going a different route.  Thanks for looking.